# Using JsonPath to extract inhomogeneous list as typed objects

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I need to parse json with a list of inhomogeneous "items" i.e. each may have different keys/structure but they share one common key (here called "a") that gives the type of the item.

```
{
  "items":[
    {"a":1, "d":2},
    {"a":2, "b":{"c":2}}
  ]
}
```

One way I thought to do this might be to pick out the json string for each "item" from the list at path "$.items" using something like the following,

```
List<String> jsonStrings = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.items");
```

such that the first string would be '{"a":1, "d":2}' and the second would be '{"a":2, "b":{"c":2}}'. This is so that I can continue to ask questions of the inner bits using JsonPath itself. Is this possible? (The code above fails as JsonPath returns a list of maps instead.)

An alternative solution might be to use a JsonPath "query path" (my term) to return only "items" with e.g. a = 2 as a list of maps - or a list of typed objects that match the nested structure of each item type, (perhaps sharing a super interface containing the type key as a field). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`$.items` doesn't work because it's not a list of strings. It's an array of JSON objects.

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but there are several ways to handle it:

```
$.items.[*].a
```

Will return all values of `a`. This might be okay if everything has an `a`:

```
[1, 2]
```

If you want to get something with a specific value for `a`, you can use the following syntax:

```
$.items[?(@.a == 2)]
```

This returns:

```
[
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": {
      "c": 2
    }
  }
]
```

See the [JSONPath Github](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) page for other examples.